# Query with ROWNUM returns differents rows on every execution

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a query that is used to search for a list of sub divisions in our network. When the query is executed without any filter, it returns a different amount of rows on every execution

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.ZRESUBDIV,
    t1.SUBDIV_NAME
FROM M_STAGE_WP_PFUNCT_LOC t1
WHERE ROWNUM <= 200  -- normally a filter goes here
ORDER BY t1.SUBDIV_NAME
```

Execution 1

```
ZRESUBDIV    SUBDIV_NAME                                                
------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
262          ALEXANDRIA                                                  
400          ALLANWATER                                                  
671          ASHCROFT                                                    
372          BALA                                                        
277          BEACHBURG                                                   
200          BRIDGE                                                      
374          CARAMAT                                                     
543          CENTRAL BUTTE                                               
208          CHAPAIS                                                     
324          CHATHAM                                                     
340          CHICAGO                                                     
...
```

Execution 2

```
ZRESUBDIV    SUBDIV_NAME                                                
------------ ------------------------------------------------------------
670          ALBREDA                                                     
262          ALEXANDRIA                                                  
400          ALLANWATER                                                  
671          ASHCROFT                                                    
372          BALA                                                        
277          BEACHBURG                                                   
604          BLACKFOOT                                                   
200          BRIDGE                                                      
607          CAMROSE                                                     
354          CASO                                                        
543          CENTRAL BUTTE                                               
...
```

There is also missing data: the subdivision Baton Rouge never appears although it is in the data.

If I remove the ROWNUM, all data is correctly returned. I need to leave ROWNUM since the query support a WHERE clause with a filter on the subdivision name.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ROWNUM` is evaluated before `ORDER BY`, that is not how `ROWNUM` should be used. To use `ROWNUM` properly, use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      t1.ZRESUBDIV,
      t1.SUBDIV_NAME
  FROM M_STAGE_WP_PFUNCT_LOC t1
  ORDER BY t1.SUBDIV_NAME
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 200;
```

But this is old. Since you are on 12c, use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.ZRESUBDIV,
    t1.SUBDIV_NAME
FROM M_STAGE_WP_PFUNCT_LOC t1
ORDER BY t1.SUBDIV_NAME
FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 7):

`ROWNUM` is the wrong way of doing this kind of query. As @Kris Johnston explains in a comment with the "cart and the horse" simile: The `WHERE` clause is executed before the `ORDER BY`, and you can't guarantee the order of the results without the `ORDER BY`, so yes, different results per run would be expected.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and a subquery instead:

```
SELECT
    t.ZRESUBDIV,
    t.SUBDIV_NAME
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        t1.ZRESUBDIV,
        t1.SUBDIV_NAME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.SUBDIV_NAME) AS RN
    FROM M_STAGE_WP_PFUNCT_LOC t1
    WHERE --- your filter goes here but NOT any ROWNUM
    GROUP BY
        t1.ZRESUBDIV,
        t1.SUBDIV_NAME
  ) t
WHERE
    t.RN <= 200
ORDER BY
    t.SUBDIV_NAME ;
```

The internal `ORDER BY` defines which rows will be selected (as the first 200 will have row_numbers from 1 to 200) and the external `ORDER BY`, wcich is optional, will only matter for the presentation order.

Note that the ordering is not total, i.e. you may have rows with same `SUBDIV_NAME`. If you want the order to be totally specified, you can change those `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY SUBDIV_NAME, BYZRESUBDIV` (for example).

The other 2 queries in @Balazs Papp's answer are also fine, if not better. The first is probably widely used as it works in older versions, before the `ROW_NUMBER()` was implemented. The 2nd is surely the most concise you can get, as long you are in 12c version.